# dropzone.js file showing but no delete link visible

Tags: javascript, php, dropzone.js

I'm trying to make an upload form in PHP /JS using the dropzone library.
I can succesfully upload the file into the database but when it is uploaded there should be a link "Remove this". I know that the return value of "addfile" is not correct but i can't seem to get it working. Can someone help me out?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _ref;

Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    addRemoveLinks: true,
    addedfile: function(file) {
        var file_data = $("#file").val();

            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/client/logo/upload',
            data: { file: file_data }
        }); 

        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ?  : void 0; 
  },

    removedfile: function(file) {
        var name = file.name;
        var time = file.lastModified;  

        console.debug(file);
        //alert(name);
        //alert(time);

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/client/file/delete',
            data: { name: name, time: time }
        });

        return (_ref = file.previewElement) != null ? _ref.parentNode.removeChild(file.previewElement) : void 0;        
    }
}
```

Comment: Can someone help me out?